# Insert document WHERE with MongoDB/mongoose

Tags: mongodb, insert, mongoose

I'm trying to insert same new object with the same name into my collection

Example;

```
//BEFORE
{
_id: HasiduhIDuad*7d89adajd,
nickname: "Clark",
password: "hush",
info : {
        info1: "test"
        }
}

// AFTER
{
_id: HasiduhIDuad*7d89adajd,
nickname: "Clark",
password: "hush",
info : {
        info1: "test"
        }
info : {
        info1: "test"
        }
}

// Add in collection WHERE nickname === "Clark" object named "info"
```

I tried with update but this is updating current info, I need to add another one.

Tried with ;

```
getCollection.update({name: "Clark"}, {
    $set: { 
        info: {
          info: "test"
        }
    }
})
```

How can I make this work ?

Comment: I am sorry but it is simply not possible to do so. You should use an array instead and push new object to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible you need to add as arrays like this;

```
getCollection.findOne({name: "Clark"}, function(err, data){
  data.info.push({info: "test"}); // push in data new object
  data.save() // save data with new object
});
```

Don't forget to change your Schema where `info` is into `info: []`